# The meaning of the word "constituencies" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *constituencies* mean in this phrase:

> The design of the used implementation of the software is distributed
>   over different design constituencies, sometimes located in two or more
>   organisations.

The dictionary specifies that the word *constituency* reffers to **a group of voters in a specified area who elect a representative to a legislative body.**

But the phrase above has nothing to do with politics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for the full term - `Design constituencies` - I found this quote:

> The **design constituency** also helps to ensure that the results inform strategic planning. **Design constituencies** open up design processes to the different stakeholders (Wessels et al., 2009; Balka et al., 2008). The aim is to include all those involved in service change...

([Source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=LN6WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22design+constituencies%22&source=bl&ots=K9-4lDeCjN&sig=QajF1cIDq4jJrqRNwkfPW2HolMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaqYDujpjYAhWRZFAKHT1QAbEQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22design%20constituencies%22&f=false))

It suggests that `Design constituencies` is referring to all the groups of people having a say in what the design will look like. In a way, `constituency` does have the same meaning here as in politics - both refer to a group of people that have a say/vote/influence regarding some decision/outcome.